# AngularFire Pause / Resume Sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Has anyone been able to pause / resume sync using Angular fire?

New to the Firebase/ AngularJS (Angularfire) stuff.

I've try nulling the objects and re initializing them on the click of a button but it doesnt do anything,

Thanks for any input.

Steve

Code as requested

```
var app = angular.module("imageanalyser-app", ["firebase"]);


var ref = null;
function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
    ref = new Firebase("...");
    $scope.messages = $firebase(ref.endAt().limit(100));

}
function resumeSync() {
    $("#btnResume").click(function() {
        ref = new Firebase("...");
    });
}

function stopSync() {
    $("#btnStop").click(function () {
        ref = null;
    });
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div ng-app="imageanalyser-app">
        <div id="links" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="MyController">

            <div ng-repeat="msg in messages" class="gallery-item-container">
                <a href="{{msg.highResUrl}}"  data-gallery>
                    <img ng-src="{{msg.Source}}" height="20" width="20"  style="position: absolute"/>
                    <img ng-src="{{msg.imgUrl}}" class="gallery-item-image" />
                </a>
                <div class="gallery-item-tags" ng-repeat="tag in msg.tags">{{tag}}</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you paste your code in?

Comment: Done, sorry should of put it in first

Comment: If you're holding onto the native Firebase reference, you can use the goOffline and goOnline methods. See docs @ https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/gooffline.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me says it doesnt contain method gooffline or online... strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, using the $off() to stop sync and then reinitialize it.

```
var fireBaseRef;
var synced = true;
function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
    fireBaseRef = new Firebase("......");
    $scope.messages = $firebase(fireBaseRef.endAt().limit(100));

    jQuery("#btnToggleState").click(function () {
        if (synced) {
            $scope.messages.$off();
            synced = false;
        } else {
            $scope.messages = $firebase(fireBaseRef.endAt().limit(100));
            synced = true;
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're updating `ref`, but never changing `$scope.messages`.  The ng-repeat is based on `$scope.messages`, so it won't change either!

To get this to behave as you want you'll need to affect the messages variable.

Comment: This is probably the way to go but... what can i do to stop the sync, if i set it to null everything thats bound to it gets remove from the page. I found $scope.messages.$off() to stop the sync.. found on https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html but a way to restart the sync? Doesn't seem to be anything there